# Hadoop hdfs, java client cannot connect to hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to connect my java client to my hadoop HDFS,
but i am stuck when i try to get the fs from my configuration

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", _PATH_);
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
FileSystem f = FileSystem.get( conf );
```

Then I get this exp..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback not org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider
```

I googled it but noting handfull come.
Any advices?

PS: I use the package hadoop-common, hadoop-hdfs from 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0

Thanks
Anthony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Code:

```
Path coreSitePath = new Path("/path/of/HADOOP_HOME", "conf/core-site.xml");
conf.addResource(coreSitePath);
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer but my hadoop_home is on a server, I try to run my client on my computer.

Comment: I tried your solution (i copied core-site from server to my computer) and i still get the same Exception JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback

Comment: I tried it in the same way u have done, it worked for me 


Configuration conf = new Configuration();

conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://hostname:9000/");  
    
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

Comment: just check there might be an issue with versions of jars you are using

Comment: Hello, may I ask you two question? Which version of hadoop HDFS do you use ? And where do you download the HDFS client java jar package ? I cannot find a valid hadoop HDFS client jar package for 2.7.1 hadoop HDFS.